# Iniciar um vetor dentro de uma struct

Tags: c

Boa tarde. Desejo iniciar um vetor de inteiros dentro de uma struct, porém ta acusando que necessita de um ";".
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue a imagem. Obs: nao é a virgula dps do ultimo zero o problema, pois tirei a print antes de tirar, e mesmo dps de tirar continua com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Olá, poderia colocar o seu código dentro da pergunta, de forma textual? Não é necessário remover a imagem, mas é importante ter as partes essenciais do seu código fonte no corpo da pergunta. Aprenda porque não é legal colocar imagens em perguntas [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3774). Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar e executar o seu código. Imagens não desempenham bem nos mecanismos de busca pelo fato do conteúdo não poder ser indexado.

Answer (score 0):

Se n me engano, não é possível declarar o valor de uma variavel dentro de um struct. Vc vai ter que inicializar ela, algo assim:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
     procedimento.dente[i] = 0;
 }
```